# <div> of images, retrieved by getJSON, disappear after append()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm working on a GMaps application to retrieve images, via getJSON(), and to populate a popup marker.

The following is the markup which I add to the marker dynamically:

```
<div id="images"></div>                 
<div id="CampWindow" style="display:none;width:550px;height:500px;">
<h4 id="camp-title"></h4>
<p>View... (all links open in new windows)</p>
<ul>
    <li><a id="camp-hp-link" target="_blank" href="">camp home page</a></li>
    <li>information: <a id="camp-av-link" target="_blank" href="">availability</a> | <a id="camp-vi-link" target="_blank" href="">vital information</li>
</ul>
<p id="message"></p>
```

I've been clawing out my eyes and woohoo for the past couple of days, trying to get the images to show inside the CampWindow . Then, I decided to think laterally and to see if the images were being retrieved at all. I then moved the images  outside and sure as Bob (Hope), the images were being retrieved and refreshed with every click.

So, I decided to the keep the images  outside and then once loaded, append it to the CampWindow . It's not working still; when I append the div to the main CampWindow div, the images won't show. I check in Firebug with the pointer thingy and it shows me the images  as empty. I try it again with the images  outside and it shows the images. I've tried before append and appendTo with no success. Am I missing something here?

I have no more woohoo to claw out. Please, please help.

```
  marker.clicked = function(marker){
    $("#images").html('');
    $('#camp-title').text(this.name);
    $('#camp-hp-link').attr('href', this.url);
    $('#camp-av-link').attr('href', this.url + '/tourism/availability.php');
    $('#camp-vi-link').attr('href', this.url + '/tourism/general.php');          

    // get resort images via jQuery AJAX call - includes/GetResortImages.inc.php
    $.getJSON('./includes/GetResortImages.inc.php', { park: this.park_name, camp: this.camp_name }, RetrieveImages);

    function RetrieveImages (data)
    {
      if ('failed' == data.status)
      {
        $('#messages').append("<em>We don't have any images for this rest camp right now!</em>");
      }
      else
      {
        if ('' != data.camp)
        {   
          $.each(data, function(key,value){
              $("<img/>").attr("src", value).appendTo('#images');
          }); 
        }
      }
    }
          //.append($("#images"));
    $("#CampWindow").show(); 
    var windowContent = $("<html />");              
    $("#CampWindow").appendTo(windowContent);        

    var infoWindowAnchor = marker.getIcon().infoWindowAnchor;
    var iconAnchor = marker.getIcon().iconAnchor;
    var offset = new google.maps.Size(infoWindowAnchor.x-iconAnchor.x,infoWindowAnchor.y-iconAnchor.y);
    map.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng(), windowContent.html(), {pixelOffset:offset});             
  }
  markers.push(marker);
});
```

Comment: do you have a live example up anywhere?

Comment: I hope the "CampWindow" div endtag is somewhere else in your code, and also that `display:none` disappears along the way...

Comment: Have you verified that "value" in $("<img/>").attr("src", value).appendTo('#images'); has content?

Comment: That's just absolutely not the way you go about creating a new window.  What you want is the `window.open()` function.

Comment: @jAndy: I don't know if I can release this to the public. But I'll think of something.

@Victor: it is.. at the bottom of the include I'm working in and I deal with display:none by calling $("#CampWindow").show()

@Kyle: yes, I have. It's definitely returning the image data and I have confirmed that it creates the image tags.

@Pointy: OK.. could you advise on how to approach the code with window.open()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `<html>` tag to your page it confuses the browser and is most likely the problem. I would suggest to either do as Pointy said and use `window.open()` to make a popup window (check out [this tutorial)](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm), or better yet try out one of the many [jQuery light box plugins](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts).

---

I'm not sure what you are doing with the google maps, so I decided to just go with a basic example for you. With this script, if you click on an image inside the `#image` div, it'll open a popup window the same size as the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#images img').click(function(){
  var padding = 20;
  var w = $(this).width() + padding;
  var h = $(this).height() + padding;
  var popup = '\
   <html>\
    <head>\
     <link type="text/css" href="popup-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />\
     <scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>\
    </head>\
    <body>\
    <img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">\
    </body>\
   </html>';
  var pop = window.open('','Image View','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
  pop.document.write(popup);
  pop.document.close();
 })
});
```

NOTE: When adding a script tag inside a string, make sure you break up the word "script" otherwise you will get an error.

---

Update #2: 
Ok, since you want to work with what you have, try doing this:

Remove the `<html>` tag from your campwindow, then position your campwindow using CSS and/or javascript. Add something like:

```
 var w = $(window).width();
 var h = $(window).height();
 // Add overlay and make clickable to hide popup
 // you can remove the background color and opacity if you want to make it invisible
 var $overlay = $('<div/>', {
  'id': 'overlay',
  css: {
   position   : 'absolute',
   height     : h + 'px',
   width      : w + 'px',
   left       : 0,
   top        : 0,
   background : '#000',
   opacity    : 0.5,
   zIndex     : 99
  }
 }).appendTo('body');
 // Position your popup window in the viewport
 $('#CampWindow').css({
  position: 'absolute',
  top     : $(window).scrollTop() + 50 + 'px',
  left    : w/2 - $('#CampWindow').width()/2 + 'px', // centers the popup
  zIndex  : 100
 })
 .fadeIn('slow');
 // Click overlay to hide popup
 $('#overlay').click(function(){
  $('#CampWindow').hide();
  $(this).remove(); // remove the overlay
 })
```

Comment: Hi guys Thanks a lot for your responses. The thing is, that although I agree that it may be an unelegant solution, it was working before I wanted to append divs to the marker popup. I guess that in itself says it all. Could you advise on how to go about reworking the marker popup generation with window.open()?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer. It makes the `#CampWindow` into a popup. Note, the code I used does require jQuery v1.4+. I hope it helps!

Comment: @fudgey thank you so much for the detailed answer. will try update #2 solution first; if not, shall try the 1st one. thanks muchly.

Comment: @fudgey: 2nd solution worked perfectly! thanks a lot. could you just guide me now on how to incorporate the actual GMaps marker code/popup?

Comment: I've never used GMaps before, so I would suggest asking a separate question. But just guessing, if GMap works inside of an iframe, you could put the iframe inside of your `#CampWindow` and see if it works.

Comment: I've found myself a dozen of on-line tutorials. Will figure it out. Thanks again muchly